# Will Airlines ever stop the pre-flight safety briefs?

Tags: air-travel

For a long time air travel has been the safest way to get around, with only 117 deaths per billion journey. Is it really necessary for the pre-flight briefing - you don't get them before getting on a train or other more "dangerous" transports.

And are there any airlines that don't do any at all, in my experience they are always there.

Thanks for any replies

Comment: I believe any not-on-the-ground transportation all have safety explanation. Every time I get on a boat for tour or cruise in north america, there is safety instructions and same as air planes. Trains don't need them because you can just step outside, there isn't anything extra you need to do like put a life jacket or get the oxygen mask. Although I took a seaplane in Maldives which did not have any safety instructions

Comment: @Huangism a few months ago I went on a boat tour on Bodensee in Konstanz and there was no safety brief. Saying that every boat tour has them is hard  to prove.

Comment: @undefined I edited my comment to north america

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s basically soliciting an opinion-based poll

Comment: And some of the dead died because not following what the safety briefs told us.

Comment: @Traveller no it wasn't, I was asking a question based on whether airlines are phasing this sort of thing out - I didn't ask for options

Comment: @EcSync: but you formulated the question in a polemic way. **ever** on title? How people could answer a question with *ever* without having a crystal ball?

Comment: @Huangism the safety instructions on the trains I travel on most frequently (in the UK) specifically tell you in the safety information not to leave the train unless there it is obviously unsafe to stay on board. There is an obvious danger of electrocution or being struck by a passing train.

Comment: One of the reasons air travel is so safe is because those briefings take place, along with many of the procedures and devices related to evacuation. Those are the result of learned lessons of past incidents, and they partly explain why many of the recent accidents ended up with very few casualties (see Asiana 214, Air France 358, BA 38...).

Answer (score 6):

Airlines don't do this because they want to, and they have no plans to phase out these briefings, because they are required by law.  For example, under US law they are required by [14 CFR 91.519](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.519):

> § 91.519 Passenger briefing.
>
> (a) Before each takeoff the pilot in command of an airplane carrying passengers shall ensure that all passengers have been orally briefed on -
>
> (1) Smoking. [...];
>
> (2) Use of safety belts and shoulder harnesses. [...];
>
> (3) Location and means for opening the passenger entry door and emergency exits;
>
> (4) Location of survival equipment;
>
> (5) Ditching procedures and the use of flotation equipment required under § 91.509 for a flight over water; and
>
> (6) The normal and emergency use of oxygen equipment installed on the airplane.

Now, there is an exception:

> (b) The oral briefing required by paragraph (a) ... need not be given when the pilot in command determines that the passengers are familiar with the contents of the briefing.

However, for a commercial airline, it will be more expensive to make the necessary determination than it will be simply to give the briefing.

As suggested in a comment, the briefing is required because, however safe air travel may be, it is safer if the passengers have information about what to do in an emergency.  Furthermore, however repetitive and boring these briefings may be for repeat travelers, there is always a likelihood that there will be some first-time travelers on any flight.

Answer (score 1):

IATA still requires safety briefs, and they mandate that should be attractive to passengers, but airlines should not force people to listen them.

I see no push to change it.  It is a good way for cabin crew to check problematic passengers, and it is almost at zero cost.

On last few security briefs I get from airlines extra stress not to take carry on baggage in case of evacuation.  We know that in few last incidents (Russia, USA), there were additional injuries and death because of this.

Cost nearly zero and allow airlines to reduce civil liability.

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S., specific guidance on the in-flight briefing is given in the [FAA Advisory Circular AC-121-24](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1035568) (revision D, issued March 5, 2019), which has this to say about its purpose:

> An alert, knowledgeable person has a much better chance of surviving any life- or injury-threatening situation that could occur during passenger-carrying operations in civil aviation. Therefore, the FAA requires U.S. air carriers and commercial operators to develop oral briefings and passenger safety information briefing cards.

The pre-flight passenger briefing is also an industry (IATA) requirement and a general recommendation (ICAO), and none of that is likely to change. Repetition correlates with retention, and precisely because flight emergencies are very rare, even very frequent flyers will not have direct experience dealing with them. There is no downside for the airline in offering it, so far as I can see.

Rather than doing away with the briefing, the FAA is all about having airlines make them more appealing:

> Every passenger should be motivated to focus on the safety information in the required passenger safety briefing; however, motivating people, even when their own personal safety is involved, is not easy. One way to increase passenger motivation is to make the safety information briefings and safety information cards as interesting, entertaining, and attractive as possible.…
>
> This AC encourages individual operators to be innovative in their approach to imparting such information. This AC also encourages evaluation of passenger comprehension of the safety information throughout the development process of the videos or briefing cards, and postflight surveys should be conducted to validate passenger comprehension and mitigate the ever-increasing distractions from passenger supplied portable electronic devices (PED) used during safety briefings.…
>
> The use of “Serious Games” and computer applications are a topic of research which is looking at the efficacy of interactive, education/entertainment applications to improve the transmission and retention of safety information.… The use of smartphone applications offers a novel experience where the user interacts with the computer software to practice behaviors that were previously only available to crewmembers during computer based training exercises and passengers during an actual emergency.…

The regulatory requirement to offer an oral pre-flight briefing is laid out for operators of large aircraft ([14 CFR §91.519](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=d2fd96bc113ac522a92cd0e29729a5cf&mc=true&r=PART&n=pt14.2.91#se14.2.91_1519)), and elsewhere for commercial passenger airlines ([14 CFR §121.571](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=61c3ff6fe638458f6c67bfd27554ddb9&mc=true&node=pt14.3.121&rgn=div5#se14.3.121_1571) and §121.573), as well as the minimum topics to cover:

- smoking and smoke detector restrictions, and adherence to signs and crew instructions
- location of emergency exits
- use of safety belts, and adherence to signs and crew instructions
- location and use of any emergency flotation devices
- use of any emergency oxygen equipment
- in certain cases, seat recline during takeoff and landing, survival equipment, and location and use of the fire extinguisher
- in extended overwater operations, on the use of life preservers and other flotation devices

Answer (score 1):

The United Nations has a special agency called the International Civil Aviation Organization which publishes International Standards And Recommended Practices. They are about such things as air navigation, its infrastructure, flight inspection, prevention of unlawful interference, and facilitation of border-crossing procedures for international civil aviation and so forth. The ICAO doesn't have legal power but most everyone have enacted these documents into national law. In this case, you are looking for the [ICAO Manual on Information and Instructions for Passenger Safety (Doc 10086)](https://store.icao.int/catalogsearch/result/?category_id=2&q=10086). As with most international standards, it costs money.

Others covered the USA, let me do the EU. In the European Union, this is adopted as part of the [Commission Regulation (EU) No 965/2012](https://www.easa.europa.eu/document-library/regulations/commission-regulation-eu-no-9652012). One of the opening paragraphs instructs the relevant agencies to consider the ICAO standards when implementating the regulation:

> In order to ensure a smooth transition and a high level
> of civil aviation safety in the European Union, implementing measures should reflect the state of the art,
> including best practices, and scientific and technical
> progress in the field of air operations. Accordingly,
> technical requirements and administrative procedures
> agreed under the auspices of the International Civil
> Aviation Organisation (hereinafter ‘ICAO’) and the
> European Joint Aviation Authorities until 30 June
> 2009, as well as existing legislation pertaining to a
> specific national environment, should be considered.

About the briefing:

> The commander, in addition to complying with CAT.GEN.MPA.100, shall
>
> (7) ensure that all passengers are briefed on the location of emergency exits and the location and use of relevant
> safety and emergency equipment;

The EASA certainly relies on ICAO 10086, as this [FAQ entry](https://www.easa.europa.eu/faq/48610) shows.

Any changes would require someone motivated enough to cut through the red tape of a UN Agency. And, of course, have a good argument to convince the ICAO with. I never heard of either.